# How to send a form over a http post in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, vue.js, get

yesterday this code was working today is showing:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
> undefined"

i was able to send a http get without axios. here goes my vue code

```
<template>
  <div>

    <form id="loginForm">
      <input type="text" name="name" v-model="user.name" />
      <input type="text" name="email" v-model="user.email" />
      <input type="text" name="message" v-model="user.message" />
      <button @click="save">send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: "Contact",
  components: {
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        name: "peter",
        email: "foo@example.com",
         message: "bla bla bla",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save: function () {
      let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("loginForm"));
      this.$http
        .get("http://link.cursolinux.pt:8080/contacts", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.body);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

for my get request i am using laravel 8

```
Route::get('/contacts', function (Request $request) {
   //get the request
   $post = $request->all();
   
   //show the get request 
   //return response()->json($post);
    
   //storage in database
    \App\Models\Contact::create($post);

});
```

Comment: `this.$http` is undefined. Did you setup [vue-resource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-resource) correctly?

Comment: thanks it was undefined, now i having other problems

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to POST that data rather than use GET.

If you do want a GET you need to pass the FormData object to URLSearchParams() to convert to a query string

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#loginForm'),
  fData = new FormData(form),
  url = new URL(form.action);

url.search = new URLSearchParams(fData);

console.log(url)
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" action="https://example.com">
  <input name="name" value="foo">
  <input name="age" value="28" />

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

first i install vue-resource:

```
npm install vue-resource
```

then import vue-resource at file main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

here goes my method:

```
  methods: {
    save: function () {
      this.$http
        .get(
          "http://www.url.domain/contacts?name=" +
            this.user.name +
            "&email=" +
            this.user.email
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.body);
        });
    },
  },
```